# How to display the contents of a file in a textarea without being redirected to a new page

Tags: php, ajax, ajaxform

```
<?php

    $blacklist = array("one.jps", "two.txt", "four.html");
    $files = array_diff(glob("*.*"), $blacklist);

    foreach($files as $file)
        echo "<div class='post'><a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?file=" . $file . "'><p>" . $file . "</p></a></div>";


    if(!empty($_GET["file"]) && !in_array($_GET["file"], $blacklist) && file_exists($_GET["file"])) 
        $thesource = htmlentities(file_get_contents($_GET["file"]));

?>

<textarea rows="40" cols="100" placeholder="Source code of file" class="source"><?php if(!empty($thesource))echo $thesource; ?></textarea>
```

The above code that I am using echo's all the files that are inside a directory (apart from those in the blacklist). When the user clicks on that file, the source code (everything contained inside that file) is displayed in the textarea.

Clicking on the file will display the source code in the textarea but when you click on the file, you are sent to a new page where the source code is displayed in the textarea. In short, the code works but you are sent to a new page. How do I make it so that everything happens on the current page that you are on.

I believe I would need to use AJAX but how would I do so?

*Note that when I say file, I am talking about the files within the directory that are echoed out onto the page. They are nested inside <p> </p> elements.*

Comment: You would use AJAX to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax to load the file content to the textarea.

**NOTE**

I have assumed the textarea has an id = "source" in this example.

url- here is the page url with the get parameters where the content of the file is displayed. eg, http://example.com/get_file.php?file=abc.txt

```
function loadDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("source").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Edit**

You need to add a **onclick** event to the button to call the above function.

Heres, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcnyja9p/5/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working unless I'm doing something wrong. This is how my code looks like now: <a onclick='loadDoc()' href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?file=" . $file . "'><h4>" . $file . "</h4></a>

Comment: Also, there are multiple different files that have the onclick event added (unless it's in the wrong place) and I'm not sure if the code doesn't work because I can't send multiple AJAX requests

Comment: Thanks for the help, though the fiddle just directs me to a new page. In short, I would like the new page to be in the same page that I am in. Visit a page without going to a new URL.